# Making properties of external library visible, without importing that library

Tags: c#, .net, dll, fody-costura

For reasons I can't explain here, I need to create a single dll file that can be used in .Net Framework applications. In that library, I use a 3rd party library that can not be (directly) used/imported by the end-user application. I use Fody/Costura to bundle the library into one dll file.

In my own library, I have a class that inherits from a class in the 3rd party library. I can use that class without problems in the application, but I get compile errors when I use properties of the base class. I can avoid these compile errors by creating a "proxy" in the child class.

Is there any way to make this work, without these proxy properties?

Comment: Without a practical example it is difficult to "debug" why you have problems

Comment: You know that you can create "proxies" of the single properties in the child classes like `public new SomeType SomeProperty { { get => base.SomeProperty; } { set => base.SomeProperty = value; }`

Comment: @xanatos, that's what I'm doing. I was just wondering if there was a quicker way, than to add all these proxies. I guess not :)

Comment: You could create a Fody to do it for you...

Comment: I'm already doing that. Still need all proxies.